# Save selected to upload file in browser cache, open file from local file system

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, filesystems, local

I need to open from page files that are selected to upload. Example: I select two files, and when i click one of them (for example there will be button for each file), then this file will be opened in local pdf reader application, ms office etc. I need to open that files from local file system before the upload. My idea is to save each selected file in browser cache to allow it to be opened - loaded from this cache. How to do something like that?